# Reassigning a Java variable within a conditional

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, compiler-errors

I've got a variable, which is initialized and then dynamically reassigned in a conditional; as such:

```
int a;

if(b > 5) {
    int a = 10;
} else {
    int a = 1;
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
/path/to/file:4 a is already defined in int a = null;
```

Why can't I reassign this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
int a;
```

this is the declaration of variable. And if you try to again write it the same way in the same scope and as the variable already exists so compiler throws an error.

You need not to re-define the variable `a`, just re-assign it like this:

```
int a = 0; // note that you need to initialize the local variables before using 

if(b > 5) {
     a = 10;
} else {
     a = 1;
}
```

Comment: In this particular case, you don't need the full definition `int a = 0;`. Just `int a;` is okay. Personally I prefer doing just the declaration whenever possible.

Comment: IMHO, the re-assignment of the variable is actually even discouraged. Just declare it, then assign the value only once when you are sure of it.

Comment: ````int a;````     the compiler will always assign 'a' to 0

Answer (score 3):

You're actually *redeclaring* variable `a`, not *reassigning* its value.

Try

```
a = 10;
```

instead of

```
int a = 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Good time to use the in-line conditional operator (the "ternary operator"):

```
 int a = (b > 5) ? 10 : 1;
```